# If DB connection got lost, will JPA save the saved data later?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I would like to know if Spring JPA will save the data later if the DB connection got lost and then the connection with DB works again.

Assume that we have a `myService` with the method `save(MyEtinty myEntity)`.

And then I call this method every second.

```
myService.save(myEntity);
```

And suddenly the DB connection lost due to the WiFi is ubstable. But efter 10 minutes it works again.

Will JPA buffer the data and then load it into the database after it has restablish the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no such buffer implemented. You'll have to do it manually, if needed.

If you're using Spring Data JPA repositories, the `CrudRepository#save` method only checks if the object already exists on the database and then call `EntityManager#save` or `EntityManager#merge`.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Is there a special feature in Spring Boot JPA that can handle that for me, so I don't need to build that code by my self?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know if there's a feature that can handle that for you. I've never heard about that before.